# Inquiring does this sound like a romance scam

Tags: scams, money-transfer, money-laundering

I met an individual on Facebook dating, he stated that a contract came through and he has to go to Turkey for three months to do the job. Individual states that he is a engineer for oil rig company and doing work for Saudi Arabia that also is merged with China somehow with equipment. This is what was said, from the individual

> "I vowed never to hide anything from you my love last night I received an urgent email from a rig equipment manufacturing company in China. On the 29th of November 2020 I was contracted by a Saudi Arabian oil company to supply some oil field equipment as the country is try to produce 12,000,000bbl/day in 2021. The contract is huge and I was paid 70 percent upfront to begin with this project. So far so good the machines and equipments are now being manufactured and from the report I got from the company was that they have processed this order and it will be made ready for delivery in 2 weeks and they demand I pay the remaining balance of $450,000.00 to complete the full payment of $893,500.00 as agreed.
> I am very happy to see success in the project as I am not available to handle things myself because I would have board a flight to China for inspection but good thing we already have a long time business relationship and they are very reliable. This is very important to me because I am still expecting 30 percent remaining balance from the company as I am investing my own money to make sure this contract is executed. I know this is my personal problem but I need you to assist me login to my bank account and help me initiate this transfer to the manufacturers so I can get things moving accordingly. I trust you so much that’s why I’m asking for your assistance, I will entrust you with my personal login information to my bank account and you will help me make a one time transfer to the manufacturer as I am unable to login my banking's from the middle of the Black Sea due to suspicious login attempt. It’s really difficult for me right now and I trust you so much."

Well I did say no and was adamant about it. I just do not want to further my time in this relationship, if this is a scam. Yeah I hear people say if it sounds like a scam it is a scam. Others have made it so that everyone is suspicious.

Comment: Oil rigs come up very often in scams of this type. Look [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=oil+rig)

Comment: Facebook dating or not, you're a stranger to this person. You really think someone who is finalizing an almost million-dollar contract needs a stranger on the Web to help them?

Comment: Thank you Michael, I am staying vigilant in saying no, that I am not comfortable with it. He still continues to chat with me I am waiting for it to come up again. I always try to give others benefit of the doubt. However, I am not that gullible, that is why I have been trying to research this. You make a lot of sense with needing a stranger on web to help them. Thanks again.

Comment: The people who create these scams use certain methods to filter out those who might smell a rat. These include bad spelling or grammar, mentioning Nigeria or another West African country, and, possibly, oil rigs.

Comment: Think about this. He says his bank has blocked him logging in to his own bank account due to "suspicious login"... so he asks a complete stranger on the Web to do it for him? If the bank site won't let him in, why would it let you in? Another 'filter' is to include obviously false excuses.

Comment: This person may be managing a chain of bank transfers for money-laundering purposes. The objective would be, not to get any of your money, but to make you a 'money mule', that is, a link in a chain where dirty money ends up where they want it to go, and if law enforcement get involved, the bank records point to your computer, not the gang's. Also if it succeeds they can then threaten or blackmail you by saying you are now a criminal. Better not to continue chatting with this person. Better by far to completely break off contact and block him.

Comment: This is a scan and should be reported as such to Facebook.

Answer (score 13):

**Someone asking you for help with money on an internet dating site is always a scam**

He's going to give you someone else's account info and have you clean them out.  Now you've likely committed a felony.

Comment: I don't see where the scammer is asking for money.

Comment: “I need you to assist me login to my bank account” - it’s not his.  He’s probably gonna ask you to spot him a few thousand to grease some palms.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it’s a scam. The login details he gives you will inevitably turn out to belong to some poor sucker who has given them over in good faith (see for example many other questions on this site from people saying a “sugar daddy” has asked them for their login details so they can deposit money....)

Anyway, if you did what this “person” (most likely actually a network of people impersonating one individual and operating the scam together) asked, when you then transferred the money out of the other victim’s account and to an account controlled by the scammers, the transaction would be traced back to your computer and the police would come knocking on your door.

Cut off all contact and block them. I’m sorry you’ve experienced this.

Answer (score 1):

It very much looks like scam, due to below aspects of the statement.

- Trying to sound so credible, using terms like oil machine engineer and signing contract and huge amounts being involved
- Trying to put up a situation where the person is helpless, using terms like unable to login from the black sea, due to suspicious login attempt
- Trying to make you do this urgently, using terms like contract will be gone, one time activity and manufacturer to move on etc

Better stay away from these kinds of online scams. There are so many different ways, where people are being scammed.